# Stone Man Stay Put

Tags: gravel

I am trying to find this product that was mentioned.  I have looked under Ace/Home Depot and Lowes.  Any other ideas or links you can help me with?

Comment: one of the answers under this https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/how-can-i-keep-gravel-from-moving-out-of-my-driveway-during-winter might help

Comment: @Bamboo That's probably where they say that product mentioned.

Comment: Ah...  that never occurred to me!